# rtspsrc to udpsink and consume it back

Tags: udp, gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch

I need help to turn a rtsp stream to a udpsink (in order to push a streaming to a remote server) but I am facing few issues. So far I am trying the following commands in order to publish and consume the stream:
create:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.10.20:554 ! rtph264depay ! rndbuffersize min=1500 max=1500 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8123`

consume:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8123 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`

But the following error occurs on the consumer side:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtpbasedepayload.c(466): gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
Received invalid RTP payload, dropping
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: The stream is in the wrong format.
Additional debug info:
gstrtph264depay.c(1270): gst_rtp_h264_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
NAL unit type 27 not supported yet
```

I've tried several commands but I am not finding any solution yet, can you provide some guidance ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `rtph264depay` with `rtph264pay` in your producer pipeline. And use `decodebin` and `autovideoconvert` to get the frames out of your `rtspsrc`.

The following pipelines are based on what I read found from here:  [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/reinzor/812a1dadd62dcf2a309c9c99af92244f)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rptspsrc location= rtsp://192.168.10.20:554 ! decodebin \
! autovideoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8123
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=8123! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,\
encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```